# Delete specific jobs from Queue - Database driver

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue

I am using database driver for managing the queue jobs, let's say there are 300 jobs in queue which are running and jobs are associated with users, now I want to delete jobs for a specific user how can I do that using database driver ?

I read `InteractsWithQueue` trait helps to interact with the queue and delete the jobs but I am not sure how to delete any specific job. Any help would be appreciated.